# Получить значение из input в функцию

Tags: javascript

```
const out = document.querySelector('.out');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let y = document.querySelector('input').value;

function myFunction(ar, item) {
    ar = a;
    item = y;
    for (let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        if (ar[i] === item) {
            return out.innerHTML += i;
        }

    }
}

button.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

если ввожу числовое значение в переменную ,то функция работает ,а так ,не видит значения из инпута ,видимо.

```
function myFunction(ar, item) {
    for (let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        if (ar[i] === item) {
            return out.innerHTML += i;
        }

    }
}
myFunction(a, 2)
```

вот так работает ,а через инпут когда задаешь значение -нет

Comment: А в какой момент у вас берется значение из инпута? Может стоит в функцию это дело перенести, как думаете?

Comment: В функцию тоже ставил в значении item = document.querySelector('input'). value, он видит значение в нем , но не прогоняет значение через функцию дальше

Comment: Из инпута вы берете строку, а потом делаете строгое сравнение с числом. Потому и не работает, скорее всего

Comment: Да ,  понимаю , что беру ссылку на объект , я именно не понимаю как мне преобразовать его в число, чтобы сработала функция

Comment: https://dev.to/sanchithasr/7-ways-to-convert-a-string-to-number-in-javascript-4l

Comment: Я уже проверял , что приходит в значение item, сразу выводя после строки с присваиванием значения через out.innerHTML+= item , и выводило число , по этому уже сюда задал вопрос , ибо я точно что-то упускаю

Comment: Console.log(typeof item)  сделайте и посмотрите что получается

Comment: Выдает string, я по этому не понимаю в чем ошибка

Comment: Я же написал выше в чем проблема  и ссылку дал с разными способами сделать из строки число.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно сделать так:

```
const out = document.querySelector('.out');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
        
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function myFunction(a) {
    ar = a;
    item = document.querySelector('input').value;
    for (let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        if (ar[i] === +item) {
            return out.innerHTML += i;
        }
   }
}

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => myFunction(a));
```